# MySQL Error Code: 1442 when deleting all records from table

Tags: mysql

Need to delete all records from a table, but when I issue the command:

```
DELETE FROM table;
```

I get

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'table' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function.

What's going on? How can I work around this? I'm in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: this [pastie](http://pastie.org/10377932) works fine. There were some nightly build issues a while back with 1442

Comment: Shouldn't it be `DELETE * FROM table;`? (with a *)

Comment: @Arijoon They're equivalent.

Comment: Are you doing this in a stored function? Can you show how you're calling the function?

Comment: Your table is called  `table`? Are you trying to run the `DELETE` from a trigger or function? You can post the code that trigger or function?

Comment: @Arijoon: `*` It appears to be valid in MS Access. [13.2.2 Syntax DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html): `The syntax permits .* after each tbl_name for compatibility with Access.`.

Comment: @wchiquito, no it's called specprocessorrawlabelsfulltext which I thought was too long to type! And I am not running it from a trigger or function, just in a SQL/Query tab in MySQL Workbench. DELETE * is not necessary, it will do it without the *.

Comment: @Drew thanks for the pastie. I don't really know what it is but I will figure it out, part of the learning process. I should add that the command suddenly worked yesterday evening. It's a mystery to me.